# Call jQuery function when also using Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my jQuery's document ready, I have something like

```
function resize() {
    textChatSection.css("width", $(window).width() - $('.user-list').width());
}
```

In the DOM, I have something like

```
<div id="users" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-controller="userController">
    <img src="test.png"/>
</div>
```

In another JS controllers file, I have a `userController`. The `$scope.users` array is empty on page load, but later on can have data, so the div is not being shown.

However when it's being shown, I need to run the `resize()` function. I tried making the function global (by assigning to a variable without the `var` infront) but it also fails. What's a good way to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try [$viewContentLoaded](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView). In your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', resize);
```

Eventually you probably want to do this in a directive. You want to avoid DOM manipulation in your controller.

Comment: I've tried making the resize function global, by assigning it to a variable without the `var` keyword, but I still get the error that `resize` is undefined, most likely because it's inside document.ready.